# Bash script in postStart is not executing

Tags: kubernetes

I'm trying to run Stateful set with my own scripts, and I'm able to run first script that will spin up `mongodb` and setup some users etc, but the second script in `postStart` block, named `configure.sh` is never executed for some reason.

Here's the `StatefulSet` manifest `yaml`:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: mongo
  labels:
    component: mongo
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      component: mongo
  serviceName: mongo
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        component: mongo
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: mongo
          image: mongo:latest
          command: [ "/bin/bash", "-c" , "+m"]
          workingDir: /mongo/scripts
          args:
          - /mongo/scripts/mongo-start.sh
          livenessProbe:
            exec:
              command:
                - "bin/bash"
                - "-c"
                - mongo -u $MONGO_USER -p $MONGO_PASSWORD --eval db.adminCommand\(\"ping\"\)
            failureThreshold: 3
            successThreshold: 1
            periodSeconds: 10
            timeoutSeconds: 5
          ports:
            - containerPort: 27017
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          lifecycle:
             postStart:
               exec:
                 command: ["/bin/bash", "-c", "/mongodb/configure.sh"]
          volumeMounts:
            - name: mongo-persistent-storage
              mountPath: /data/db
            - name: mongo-scripts
              mountPath: /mongo/scripts
            - name: mongo-config
              mountPath: /mongodb/configure.sh
              subPath: configure.sh
          env:
            - name: MONGO_USER_APP_NAME
              valueFrom:
                configMapKeyRef:
                  key: MONGO_USER_APP_NAME
                  name: mongo-auth-env
            - name: MONGO_USER_APP_PASSWORD
              valueFrom:
                configMapKeyRef:
                  key: MONGO_USER_APP_PASSWORD
                  name: mongo-auth-env
            - name: MONGO_USER
              valueFrom:
                configMapKeyRef:
                  key: MONGO_USER
                  name: mongo-auth-env
            - name: MONGO_PASSWORD
              valueFrom:
                configMapKeyRef:
                  key: MONGO_PASSWORD
                  name: mongo-auth-env
            - name: MONGO_BIND_IP
              valueFrom:
                configMapKeyRef:
                  key: MONGO_BIND_IP
                  name: mongo-config-env              
      restartPolicy: Always
      volumes:
        - name: mongo-scripts
          configMap:
            name: mongo-scripts
            defaultMode: 0777
        - name: mongo-config
          configMap:
            name: mongo-config
            defaultMode: 0777
        - name: mongo-config-env
          configMap:
            name: mongo-config-env
            defaultMode: 0777
        - name: mongo-auth-env
          configMap:
            name: mongo-auth-env
            defaultMode: 0777
  volumeClaimTemplates:
    - metadata:
        name: mongo-persistent-storage
      spec:
        accessModes:
          - ReadWriteOnce
        resources:
          requests:
            storage: 1Gi
```

`mongo-start.sh` which is in `/scripts` folder with another scripts, is being executed, but after `Pod` is up and running, `configure.sh` is never executed, logs are not helpful, `kubectl describe pod` returns it as recognized, but it never runs. `ConfigMaps` are all deployed and their content and paths are also ok. Is there any other way to run the script after another, or I'm doing something wrong, been searching on `SO` and official docs, that's the only examples I found. Tnx

**EDIT**
it started somehow, but with:

```
Exec lifecycle hook ([/bin/bash -c /mongodb/mongodb-config.sh]) for Container "mongo" in Pod "mongo-0_test(e9db216d-c1c2-4f19-b85e-19b210a22bbb)" failed - error: command '/bin/bash -c /mongodb/mongodb-config.sh' exited with 1: , message: "MongoDB shell version v4.2.12\nconnecting to: mongodb://mongo:27017/?authSource=admin&compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb\n2021-11-24T22:16:50.520+0000 E  QUERY    [js] Error: couldn't connect to server mongo:27017, connection attempt failed: SocketException: Error connecting to mongo:27017 (172.20.3.3:27017) :: caused by :: Connection refused :\nconnect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:353:17\n@(connect):2:6\n2021-11-24T22:16:50.522+0000
```

Content of the configure.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
mongo --username $MONGO_USER_ROOT_NAME --password "$MONGO_USER_ROOT_PASSWORD" --authenticationDatabase "$MONGO_AUTH_SOURCE" --host mongo --port "$MONGO_PORT" < create.js
```

If I remove postStart part, and init into container, I can successfully run the script..

Answer (score 2):

There is no guarantee that `postStart` hook will be call after container entry point. Also, `postStart` hook can be called more than once. The error was because by the time `configure.sh` was executed; the mongodb was not up and running yet. If your `configure.sh` script is idempotent, you can do a wait before proceed to next step:

```
#!/bin/bash

until mongo --nodb --disableImplicitSessions --host mongo --username $MONGO_USER_ROOT_NAME --password $MONGO_USER_ROOT_PASSWORD --eval 'db.adminCommand("ping")'; do sleep 1; done

mongo --username $MONGO_USER_ROOT_NAME --password "$MONGO_USER_ROOT_PASSWORD" --authenticationDatabase "$MONGO_AUTH_SOURCE" --host mongo --port "$MONGO_PORT" < create.js
```

Comment: I tried but unfortunately, I did not manage to make this "wait" work, as I understood, I can wait for another container to start and execute some job, but I'm not sure is it possible to wait until the pod is ready and execute a command in the same container afterward, thanks

Comment: Try the updated answer which wait on the mongodb instead of pod.

Comment: got `syntax error near unexpected token ('
/mongodb/mongodb-config.sh: line 2: until mongo --nodb --disableImplicitSessions --host mongo --username $MONGO_USER_ROOT_NAME --password $MONGO_USER_ROOT_PASSWORD --eval db.adminCommand('ping'); do sleep 1; done'`

Comment: Forgotten the quote, try again.